# Retrieve coordinates for ImageView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I would like to know if it is possible to get the coordinates, left and top, of an ImageView.
I have 2 ImageView inside a RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView.
I tried to retrieve the matrix of the ImageView with `matrix = _iv.getImageMatrix();` but it is not helpful `Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`. 
Any ideas? Would it make a difference if the `getImageMatix()` is run in a different place?

Comment: you want to get co-ordinates of ImageView onClick event...?

Comment: The event will give me the screen coordinates, which I want to correlate with the ImageView, no matter where on the screen is located. That's why I am looking for its coordinates from the screen.

Comment: yes but you can get it on any of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better way to do it. I implemented an OnTouchListener in the ImageView itself and the X,Y coordinates are corresponding to the ImageView.

```
_iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Choose which motion action has been performed
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Get X, Y coordinates from the ImageView
                int X = (int) event.getX();
                int Y = (int) event.getY();

                //Do something

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
}); //End setOnTouchListner()
```