# How to get correct imageview coordinates with moveable image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I would like to be able to view a rather large image (floor plan) that can be fully viewed by moving around the picture. When I click on the image, I would also like to get the coordinates on that image.

I've followed this tutorial [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSBij.png) which works correctly and so allows me to move around the image. After that I also added some functionality to get the position of where I touch the screen. However, when moving around the image, black borders surround it (see picture below), which causes me to get incorrect coordinates.

So would somebody know how I could a) fix/remove the black borders when moving the image or b) correct the coordinates I receive by e.g. removing the border offset?

[image: Before moving the image][image: After moving the image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSBij.png) http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/1763

Answer (score 1):

When you move around the image, set the scroll to stop before it reaches the edges of the image. Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773206/where-does-android-view-scrolltox-y-scroll-to/7851835#7851835) for further details.

As for your coordinates, check these other 2 links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745540/get-coordinates-of-a-bitmap-image-from-an-imageview-twice-as-small/7800238#7800238), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689690/retrieve-coordinates-for-imageview/7713533#7713533).

Hope these would help you.